# AS3 AIR URLLoader POST

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, air

I am developing my first AIR app (moving over from PHP/Javascript) and am at a stage where I want to send some data from the app back to a PHP script on my server. I have the following:

```
var url:String = "PHP URL HERE";
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);

var requestVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
requestVars.test = "1234";

request.data = requestVars;
request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
request.contentType = "application/xml;charset=utf-8";

var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
urlLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processSERPS, false, 0, true);
urlLoader.load(request);
```

I did have something else in the server side PHP script originally but for debugging I just changed it to dump the REQUEST array.

With the code above it will simply return nothing:

```
Array
(
)
```

But if I change the request method to Get:

```
request.method = URLRequestMethod.GET;
```

I receive:

```
Array
(
    [test] => 1234
)
```

Which tells me that the code is correct, it just isn't sending the post parameters for some reason.

I would just alter the code to use GET variables but unfortunately the data I need to send is too large hence the need for POST.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: isnt php code different depending on whether extracting POST or GET data? so i assume your php code only works with GET

Comment: Unfortunately the PHP part of this is the only part I am confident about. I am using REQUEST in the PHP which should show GET or POST. Even if I specifically set it to echo POST variables it doesn't show any.

Comment: What happens if you remove the line with `request.contentType = "application/xml;charset=utf-8";`? This looks like the wrong content type for POST data to me.

Comment: Yep, the answer below further clarified this for me. Setting content type to application/x-www-form-urlencoded fixed it. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

For [URLRequest.contentType](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLRequest.html#contentType):

> If the value of the data property is a URLVariables object, the value
>   of contentType must be application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

This is the default value, so just removing your assignment should do it.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't originally set the content type but came across a post somewhere else where somebody set the type to XML and it made post values work correctly hence me modifying it. For some reason (I blame windows 8) if I leave it blank it doesnt work, but set it to 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' and the post values come through.